# C# & SQL Server stored procedure - updating entity with a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

At one point, there was a `Node` entity that had a field `Alias`. However, things have changed, and now we have modified that data model so that a `Node` can have multiple `Aliases`, and therefore, a `Node` now support an array of `Aliases` (which in turn creates an `Aliases` table, and an `AliasesNodes` table that maps the many-to-many relationship).

My question is, how do I update my stored procedure so that it supports this, and how do I modify the c# code that calls this stored procedure?

The requirements from the procedure is to only insert a `Node` if it doesn't exists, for each `Alias`, only insert if it doesn't exist, and finally, create the relationships between the `Node` and its `Aliases`.

**OLD** working stored procedure when `Alias` was a field (before an `Alias` table existed):

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[NodeTableType] AS TABLE
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NodeTypeId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Location] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DisplayName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [AccessLevel] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [IsEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [ModifiedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [NativeId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SourceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Alias] [nvarchar](100) NULL
);

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertNonExistingNode] 
    (@TableVariable dbo.NodeTableType READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO NWatchNodes WITH (ROWLOCK) (Id, NodeTypeId, Location, DisplayName, 
                AccessLevel, IsEnabled, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, 
                ModifiedOn, ModifiedBy, NativeId, SourceId, Name, Alias) 
        SELECT
            t.Id, t.NodeTypeId, t.Location, t.DisplayName,
            t.AccessLevel, t.IsEnabled, t.CreatedOn, t.CreatedBy,
            t.ModifiedOn, t.ModifiedBy, t.NativeId, t.SourceId, t.Name, t.Alias
        FROM 
            @TableVariable t
        LEFT JOIN 
            NWatchNodes PR WITH (NOLOCK) ON  PR.Id = t.Id
        WHERE 
            PR.ID IS NULL
END;
```

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Your question is not very clear. In the meantime I suggest you read up about NOLOCK...unless of course you are ok with occasionally getting duplicate and/or missing rows. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @SeanLange I am using ROWLOCK, not NOLOCK.  Was that a mistake on your part?

Comment: @blgrnboy You have NOLOCK at the end of query when you read from `NWatchNodes`. It can cause to get bad data from that table.

Comment: The NOLOCK is part of your select statement in the final insert. That is a decision you need to make. The challenge here is that your question is not very clear so it is very difficult for others to help. You can probably find a great starting point here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange for pointing that out.  I am not very strong in SQL.  Do you suggest a ROWLOCK for the final statement?

Comment: I suggest not using a query hint at all. When you use query hints it is saying that you know better how to handle locking than the sql engine. For almost everybody that is probably not the case. I would let the engine handle locking for you unless your testing has proven you need to specify locking for a specific reason. Locking is complex topic so if you are not really knowledgeable on the topic it is probably best left to the sql engine.